# Convert unrecognized type string to System::String (C++/CLI)

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I've been struggling with a new project in C++/CLI. I managed to fix most of my problems on this language (most of them were about translation from either C# or native C++ codes). But I still have one big problem:

I'm using a (native) C++ library as unmanaged code to retrieve information on images and stuff (basic OCR). This library gives me specific types on output. Most of them are either bool or int, so I can handle them in C++/cli, but I have a non-standard string output format (gxOutString) that I can't process. I just get an error saying:

```
m_codeString = reader.GetCodeString();
"there is no conversion between "gxOutString" and "System::String ^"
```

I know the images are processed and the code string recognized by the library (because checksum validations are returned true, also other variables checks out), but I haven't managed to do anything with this string which is the most important element to retrieve.

In console native C++ though, this variable can be printed in cout normally, and handled by C++ in Qt via QtString apparently (from other programs I have as examples).

How can I process this type so the rest of the managed C++/cli code can understand it?

Comment: Look at the documentation for that library and see if they have any conversions to c-strings or C++ strings. If you can get that, then it is easy to get to a `System::String^`.

Comment: I didn't found anything in the library documentation but I remember some components are handled with yet another library we don't have the doc for, but we have some of the source code.

Exploring those files I found this reference:

`typedef std::string gxOutAString;`

`typedef std::wstring gxOutString;`

So looks like it's just a _std::string_.
Gonna have some fun with the Marshall then...

Comment: Pretty simple, actually: `x = marshal_as<String^>(cppstring);`

Comment: Is this way better than the one I described as an answer?

Answer (score -2):

So after some more investigation I found two references in a header (from yet another library I use):

```
typedef std::string gxOutAString;
typedef std::wstring gxOutString;
```

So turns out it's a *std::string* after all.

My solution for conversion then:

```
gxOutAString temp_codeString = reader.GetCodeString();
m_codeString = gcnew String(temp_codeString.c_str());
```

Seems to work fine even if I'm still figuring out how the Marshall works for "reverse" conversions.
Thank you anyway. 
That's incredible how a crippling error can be fixed just by explaining it and getting small suggestions.